# Where'd My Ubuntu Install go?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, windows-8, debian

This <strike>may be</strike> probably is a newbie question, but I've used Ubuntu before and haven't had issues.

Today, I decided to put a linux OS on my HP Pavilion G6 laptop (Win8). Since I tried Ubuntu before, I decided to check out a new flavor and got myself Debian Wheezy, put it on a live DVD, made necessary changes to windows (partitioning, turned off fast-boot, turned on legacy), tried it, installed, and all worked pretty well. Determined that I want to stick with Ubuntu for now (sucker for eye candy), grabbed 14.10, made a DVD, and rebooted into the installer. I took the Debian partition, shrunk it, and told Ubuntu to do its thing. Installation seemed to be fine, and I allowed it to do updates from the web. Pressed the "restart now" button and...I can't find Ubuntu.

It's not in Grub that installed with Debian (although I saw ubuntu doing something with Grub during the install), and it's not obviously available through the default loader (just boots HP, no obvious questions/opportunity to switch OS's). Should I reinstall? All the files seem to be where I expected them to be, when I look for them in Debian.

Both Debian and Win8 still are booting and running happily.

The following are available under Grub (with Debian logo in background) after `esc -> f9 -> notebook harddisk`:

```
Debian GNU Linux, Linux 3.2.0-4-AMD64
Debian GNU Linux, Linux 3.2.0-4-AMD64 recovery mode
4 different Memory Tests
Windows Vista Loader <- This one gives an error and won't boot into win8
Windows Vista Loader <- haven't tried this one yet [and why does it say vista?]
```

To get to Windows, I just don't touch anything and it boots happily. Haven't tried to load it from Grub.

System Specs:

```
HP Pavilion G6
AMD A6 Vision
Windows 8
Debian Wheezy AMD 64 (latest stable)
Ubuntu 14.10 Utopic Unicorn AMD 64 (Just got it today, so should be latest)
```

Is there (another) Grub somewhere that I'm missing? Can I manually add Ubuntu to the Grub loader that is running for Debian?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo update-grub` from your Debian since you installed Ubuntu?

Comment: Just did, no luck. It told me about 4 images that it found but no change to the actual menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GRUB is made up of two parts, a small bootloader that goes into the boot loader (probably MBR, but don't know for sure with your system), and another section with the menu that goes into the system's /boot/grub directory.  The bootloader must know where the other section is located.

So, you have two grub menus:  one in your Debian installation (which is the one being used), and one in the Ubuntu installation, which is not being used.

You need to tell the bootloader which one to use, and most likely when you installed Ubuntu, you told it to load the bootloader into the Ubuntu partition rather than the MBR.  But there is a way to fix it.  `update-grub` won't do it; all that does is to update the menu in /boot/grub to configure any changes made to configuration files.  What you need to run is `grub-install`. The easiest way to do this is to boot from any system other than Ubuntu that uses the same version of GRUB, such as the Ubuntu installation CD/USB, then mount the Ubuntu partition.

For example, say you mount the disk to the directory `/mnt` (assume `/dev/sda` for this example... `sudo mount /mnt /dev/sda???`, where ??? is the partition containing Ubuntu).  Once you do this, the command would be:

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
```

You should not need to run `update-grub`, as the menu should be OK once it's actually read.

**Edit after comment**
It may be that the option `--root-directory` has been made obsolescent; I'm pretty sure I've used it with this version, but it is not listed in the man pages anymore.  [This article]((http://www.av8n.com/computer/htm/grub-reinstall.htm) shows its usage with a lot more details.

I believe the current syntax may be `sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sda`, but I haven't tried this myself; an example is shown if you use `info grub-install`.  The "--boot-directory" option specifies the full path to the boot directory, which is actually more clear; the old version assumed that you would use a directory named "boot" in the specified root directory, which is the default, but not necessarily what is wanted.

Do you have a directory /media/ubuntu/long_hashed_looking_string/boot/grub/i386-pc?  That's where modinfo.sh is on my system.  The "--boot-directory" option actually is specifying where the grub.cfg file resides, which is what the grub bootloader looks for to display the menu.

I actually meant to mount using the `mount` command, such as `sudo mount dev dir`, eg `sudo mount /dev/sda?? /mnt`.  It's quick and easy to find, although it will hide any other files under /mnt, so I usually have something like `/mnt/temp` for things like this.

Comment: Can you give me a bit more info? I've tried to run grub-install but there's not a `--root-directory` option listed `grub-install --help`. I also am not sure what you mean by mount - if I mount '139GB Volume' in "files" and use the directory names, it tells me `/media/ubuntu/long_hashed_looking_string/boot/grub/modinfo.sh doesn't exist`.

Comment: @Josiah - I added an edit to answer (I hope) your questions.

Comment: Thanks for your help. You were correct about what happened - I ended up doing a reinstall between trying your original answer and your edit, ensuring I told the installer to use the harddrive (not one of the partitions) as the location for Grub. This solved the problem, but unfortunately, I cannot test the rest of your answer to see if it solves it. Thanks for putting me on the right track - researching the information you gave helped me to learn a lot about Grub.

Comment: @josia - I'm glad I was helpful.  Grub isn't really too complicated once you understand how there are two parts, on for the boot record, and another for the menu.  The boot code just needs to know where to find the menu.